# Calculate current time from next minitue then NSTimer should not work

Tags: ios, iphone, nstimer

hi i am kind of new to iOS.Now i have confused with this concept..the concept is that i want to get current time(HH:MM:SS)when i click the button.Inside the button i have done something repeating task by using `NSTimer`.once i get the current time after one minitue the NSTimer sholud invalidate(the nstimer is call each(0.05f)).Here i need to calculate pressing time with next one minitue.thanks in advance.sorry dont mistake me i am stupid in english.
here is the code i am still now..

```
- (void) scanButtonTouchUpInside {


    if (check) {
        position=CGPointMake(14.0f, 7.0f);
        position1=CGPointMake(7.0f, 14.0f);
        check=NO;

       timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



    }
  else
  {
      //animation stop code here.................
      if ([timer isValid]) {
          [timer invalidate];
      }
      check=YES;
      NSLog(@"stopppppppp.....................");
//      overlayGraphicView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 32, 32);
//      overlayGraphicView1.frame = CGRectMake(30, 152, 32, 32);
  }


}

-(void)onTimer
{


    overlayGraphicView.center = CGPointMake(overlayGraphicView.center.x+position.x,overlayGraphicView.center.y+position.y);

    if(overlayGraphicView.center.x > 320 || overlayGraphicView.center.x < 0)
        position.x = -position.x;
    if(overlayGraphicView.center.y > 480 || overlayGraphicView.center.y < 0)
        position.y = -position.y;



    overlayGraphicView1.center = CGPointMake(overlayGraphicView1.center.x+position1.x,overlayGraphicView1.center.y+position1.y);

    if(overlayGraphicView1.center.x > 320 || overlayGraphicView1.center.x < 0)
        position1.x = -position1.x;
    if(overlayGraphicView1.center.y > 480 || overlayGraphicView1.center.y < 0)
        position1.y = -position1.y;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

First `scanButtonTouchUpInside` will run once because you start the timer there
`timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

And when the method `onTimer` run, nothing call `scanButtonTouchUpInside` again, so you need add `[self scanButtonTouchUpInside];` at the end.

Second, to calculate the you need to do this

```
-(NSInteger)calculateMinutesFromLastDate:(NSDate *)lastDate toNow:(NSDate *)nowDate
    NSDateComponents *nowDateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:nowDate];
    NSInteger nowCurrentMinute = [nowDateComponents minute];

    NSDateComponents *lastDateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:lastDate];
    NSInteger lastMinute = [lastDateComponents minute];
    NSInteger differenceMinutes = nowCurrentMinute - lastMinute;

    return differenceMinutes
}
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: can you give more details about what do you want to do?

Comment: thanks @nathan hegedus i have done this in different way

Answer (score 1):

i have done this simple way...

```
-(void)onTimer
{


    overlayGraphicView.center = CGPointMake(overlayGraphicView.center.x+position.x,overlayGraphicView.center.y+position.y);

    if(overlayGraphicView.center.x > 320 || overlayGraphicView.center.x < 0)
        position.x = -position.x;
    if(overlayGraphicView.center.y > 480 || overlayGraphicView.center.y < 0)
        position.y = -position.y;



    overlayGraphicView1.center = CGPointMake(overlayGraphicView1.center.x+position1.x,overlayGraphicView1.center.y+position1.y);

    if(overlayGraphicView1.center.x > 320 || overlayGraphicView1.center.x < 0)
        position1.x = -position1.x;
    if(overlayGraphicView1.center.y > 480 || overlayGraphicView1.center.y < 0)
        position1.y = -position1.y;
  }
- (void) scanButtonTouchUpInside {

    [self performSelector:@selector(timerInvalidate) withObject:nil afterDelay:60.0];
    if (check) {
        position=CGPointMake(14.0f, 7.0f);
        position1=CGPointMake(7.0f, 14.0f);

       timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



    }

}

-(void)timerInvalidate
{
    if ([timer isValid]) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

The overlay source taken from https://github.com/jj0b/OverlayViewTester